# Error check for int value not working

Tags: c#

I have a function that is meant to test whether or not a field in a .csv contains a valid id (ProfileID in this case). I want to check for non-numeric entries and display an error message if this is true. However, I don't understand why the function I have setup fails to catch the error. The import process still produces an error page with the message: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '9b' to data type int" (9B is the invalid value I have in my test .csv file).

This is the code:

```
    bool RetVal = true;

    //PROFILEID
    string ProfileID = GetValue(row, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId);
    try
    {
        ProfileID = ProfileID.ToLower();
        int profIDCount = 0;

        int pnumber;
        bool presult = Int32.TryParse(ProfileID, out pnumber);

        if (presult == false)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text += "Error Line " + LineCount + ": on " + ProfileID + " Invalid ProfileID<br />";
            RetVal = false;
        }

        else
        {
            string profIDSqlStr = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'ProfileID' FROM ProductProfile WHERE ProfileID=@ProfileID");
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(profIDSqlStr, cn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", ProfileID);
                cn.Open();

                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {

                        profIDCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProfileID"].ToString());
                    }
                    if (profIDCount <= 0)
                    {
                        ErrorLabel.Text += "Error Line " + LineCount + ": on " + ProfileID + " Invalid  Product Profile<br />";
                        RetVal = false;

                    }
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text += "Error Line " + LineCount + ": on " + ProfileID + " Error looking up product profile<br />";
        RetVal = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this line:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", ProfileID);
```

Your `ProfileID` is of type string , so your C# code would add it as a string , *(Surrounded by single quotes)* that is why you are getting the error. You need to pass parsed value (int) to your parameter.

<strike>Declare your int variable `pnumber` outside of the try block and initialize it with a default value.</strike>  *(no need, since scope is same)*

Just pass `pnumber` as your parameter value.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", pnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct type, so not string when it's an `int` column.

Replace

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", ProfileID);
```

with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", pnumber);
```

`pnumber` was successfully  initialized in `Int32.TryParse`.